# How to get pid in batch for cmd with parameters?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm noobie in MS batch (bat). I need to save some streaming via VLC to file.
This script working greate for me:

```
@echo off    
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "http://STREAM" --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1400,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=192,channels=2,deinterlace}:file{dst="D:\SOMEFILE.mp4"}
```

But I need to stop recording after N seconds. So I think the best way is to get pid of this proccess and run

`timeout /t 120 /nobreak
taskkill /t /pid %PID%`

For this I found some solution:

```
@echo off

set "exe=C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
set "source=http://STREAM"
set "save-cmd=--sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1400,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=192,channels=2,deinterlace}:file{dst="D:\SOMEFILE.mp4"}"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in ('wmic process call create '"%exe%" "%source%" %save-cmd%' ^| find "ProcessId"') do set PID=%%a
echo "%PID%"
timeout /t 120 /nobreak
taskkill /t /pid %PID%
```

I'm getting PID, But VLC openning in normal way (don't do anything), as I just run `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe`

How can I run programm with parameters and get PID of it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [VLC forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=41489#p274006), you can use `--run-time` and `--stop-time` parameters to close VLC after a specified amount of time.

For example adding `--run-time 120 --stop-time=120 vlc://quit` will exit after 2 hours

**Updated script:**

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "http://STREAM" --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1400,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=192,channels=2,deinterlace}:file{dst="D:\SOMEFILE.mp4"} --run-time 120 --stop-time=120 vlc://quit
```